# Генерация ip из диапазонов. Менее ресурсоемкая

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток.
Встал вопрос о генерации ip адресов из диапазонов ip адресов.
Нашел на просторах интернета данный метод:

```
public static List<IPAddress> IPAddressesRange(IPAddress firstIPAddress, IPAddress lastIPAddress)
        {
            var firstIPAddressAsBytesArray = firstIPAddress.GetAddressBytes();

            var lastIPAddressAsBytesArray = lastIPAddress.GetAddressBytes();

            Array.Reverse(firstIPAddressAsBytesArray);

            Array.Reverse(lastIPAddressAsBytesArray);

            var firstIPAddressAsInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(firstIPAddressAsBytesArray, 0);

            var lastIPAddressAsInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(lastIPAddressAsBytesArray, 0);

            var ipAddressesInTheRange = new List<IPAddress>();

            for (var i = firstIPAddressAsInt; i <= lastIPAddressAsInt; i++)
            {
                var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);

                var newIp = new IPAddress(new[] { bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0] });

                ipAddressesInTheRange.Add(newIp);
            }

            return ipAddressesInTheRange;
        }
```

Но уж очень он ресурсоемкий, к примеру если задать диапазон 192.168.1.1-193.168.1.1 метод отжирает порядка 1.5 гб озу. Буду благодарен за любые предложения по уменьшению потребления ОЗУ.

---

update

```
public static IEnumerable<List<string>> IPAddressesRange(IPAddress firstIPAddress, IPAddress lastIPAddress, int partCount)
        {
            var firstIPAddressAsBytesArray = firstIPAddress.GetAddressBytes();
            var lastIPAddressAsBytesArray = lastIPAddress.GetAddressBytes();

            Array.Reverse(firstIPAddressAsBytesArray);
            Array.Reverse(lastIPAddressAsBytesArray);

            var firstIPAddressAsInt = BitConverter.ToUInt32(firstIPAddressAsBytesArray, 0);
            var lastIPAddressAsInt = BitConverter.ToUInt32(lastIPAddressAsBytesArray, 0);

            var ipAddressesInTheRange = new List<string>();

            int count = 0;

            for (var i = firstIPAddressAsInt; i <= lastIPAddressAsInt; i++)
            {
                var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
                var newIp = new IPAddress(new[] { bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0] });
                ipAddressesInTheRange.Add(newIp.MapToIPv4().ToString());
                count++;

                if (count == partCount)
                {
                    yield return ipAddressesInTheRange;
                    ipAddressesInTheRange.Clear();
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

         yield return ipAddressesInTheRange;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде там негде тратить ресурсы. Однако, ваш пример генерирует `256^3`, то есть примерно 17 миллионов адресов.

Может, возвращайте не `List`, а `IEnumerable`? Через `yield return`. Экономия памяти 100% :)

---

Я имею в виду такой код:

```
public static IEnumerable<IPAddress> IPAddressesRange(IPAddress firstIPAddress, IPAddress lastIPAddress)
{
    var firstIPAddressAsBytesArray = firstIPAddress.GetAddressBytes();
    var lastIPAddressAsBytesArray = lastIPAddress.GetAddressBytes();

    Array.Reverse(firstIPAddressAsBytesArray);
    Array.Reverse(lastIPAddressAsBytesArray);

    var firstIPAddressAsUInt = BitConverter.ToUInt32(firstIPAddressAsBytesArray, 0);
    var lastIPAddressAsUInt = BitConverter.ToUInt32(lastIPAddressAsBytesArray, 0);

    for (var i = firstIPAddressAsUInt; i <= lastIPAddressAsUInt; i++)
    {
        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
        Array.Reverse(bytes);
        var newIp = new IPAddress(bytes);
        yield return newIp;
    }
}
```

Comment: @VladD, судя по всему это единственный вариант. Только вот из-за нарушения целостности списка нельзя удалить повторы.

Добавил в вопрос то, что получилось.

Comment: @z668: Не, подождите, лучше по-другому. Сейчас добавлю в ответ.

Comment: @z668: Ваш код делает по существу то же, что [`Batch` из MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs): разбивает длинный список на куски заданного размера.

Comment: @VladD, благодарю за реализацию с yield return Ip; Но не будет ли такая реализация медленнее? Я плохо знаком с внутренним устройством дотнета, так что извините если вопрос некорректный.

Comment: @z668: По идее, медленнее не будет. Должно быть немного быстрее за счёт отсутствия копирования.

Comment: В код вкралась ошибка. Дело в том, что максимальный размер адресного пространства ipv4 составляет: 4294967295 в десятичной системе. Нужно использовать uint вместо int.

Comment: @z668: Точно! Спасибо за уточнение! (Обновил ответ.)